# Forwarding in STRUTS

Tags: struts

I am forwarding to an action by giving  as

```
<forward  name="sample" path="/sample.do?button=default" />
```

i want to add one more attribute in path and i used:

```
<forward  name="sample" path="/sample.do?button=default&value=text" />
```

...and I am getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

As Omnipresent and Shashi already said, you must encode the ampersand as `&amp;` so that the `forward` definition looks like this:

```
<forward  name="sample" path="/sample.do?button=default&amp;value=text" />
```

However, the URLs defined in your `struts-config.xml` are frozen, and if you need to dynamically change a value or add another parameter, you can do it by creating a new `ActionForward` based on the forward that you get from `mapping.findForward()`.

```
ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("sample");
StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(forward.getPath());
path.append("?id=");
path.append(someobject.getId());
path.append("&value=");
path.append(getValue());
return new ActionForward(path.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<forward  name="sample" path="/sample.do?button=default&value=text" />
```

You can pass multiple parameter in forward. 
But you have to use '&amp;' instead of '&'.

To be strictly accurate, the parser handler should scan the buffer for ampersand characters (&);and left-angle bracket characters `(<)` and replace them with the strings &amp; or &lt;, as appropriate.

So, the forward statement will be as

```
<forward  name="sample" path="/sample.do?button=default&amp;amp;value=text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use '&' in struts-config.xml

value=text should be passed from your action...not the way you are trying to pass it (in url).

Your forward tag must be associated with an action.  that action should have a getter called value which returns 'text'.

what way sample.do will have access to that varable.